# Splitting a char* at its many '\0' chars

Tags: c++, winapi, cstring

The following is in C++.
I have a string that contains the environment variables I need to split it at the declaration of each variable & store it in a string:

```
char* envVars = "=::=::\0system=blah\0othervar=blah\0"
```

So I am using cstring functions to split the string at the occurence of the null terminator char '\0' but it's just going into an infinite loop. Why?

**SOLUTION Found: look at code comments:**

```
vector <string> GetEvironmentVariables()
{
   vector <string> envVariables;
   char* environVar = GetEnvironmentStrings();
   char* pos        = strchr( environVar, '\0' );

   // As far as I know environVar =::=::\0environVar1=...\0environVar2=...\0" 
   // so the string has many NULL terminators  

   while ( pos != NULL )
   {
       char* buffer;
       strncpy( buffer, environVar, strlen(pos) );   // on the 1st iteration: buffer SHOULD = "=::=::\0", 2nd buffer SHOULD = "environVar=...\0"
       envVariables.push_back( string(buffer) );
       environVar = pos;                            // SOLUTUION: I need to move over the '\0' pos points to so: environVar = ++pos;
       pos        = strchr( environVar, '\0' );

       printf("Var: %s \n", envVariables.back().c_str() ); 
       printf("env: %s \n", environVar);
       system("PAUSE");
       // prints out this:
       // Var: cRek (same junk each iteration)
       // env: 
       // Press any key to continue....
   }

   FreeEnvironmentStrings( environVar ); 
   return envVariables;       
}
```

Comment: How will you know that you reached the end of the string? In this case, \0 indicates the end of a single environment variable, but `envVars` has multiple environment variables in it.

Comment: @In silico: I am assuming it ends in a \0 char

Comment: @Mack: Yes but each "substring" in the string ends with a \0. How will you know that it's the last substring or that there's more after it?

Comment: @In silico: strchr() documentation says when it doesn't find the search for char it returns null, so the while loop should break.

Comment: @Mack: But how do you think `strchr()` knows when to stop searching for the `char` you pass in? `strchr()` searches the string until it finds either the character you pass in or the null terminator. `strchr()` works with the assumption that the null terminator represents the ultimate end of a string, but in this case you're using it to represent the end of a substring.

Comment: @Mack: `strchr()` only breaks at the end of a string.  The end of a string is defined as the first NUL character.  See a problem?

Comment: The environment variables end with a double `\0` I believe.

Comment: @ALL: read the strch documentation: it is one of the only cstring functions that allows you to search for a '\0' char. others stop searching when they encounter it or ignore it. "The terminating null-character is considered part of the C string. Therefore, it can also be located to retrieve a pointer to the end of a string"

Comment: @Xeo: Looking at the documentation for [`GetEnvironmentStrings()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683187.aspx), you're right. In that case, [this The Old New Thing blog post is helpful](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/10/08/9904646.aspx).

Comment: As @James has pointed out, the string will have a pair of consecutive '\0' on the end, this can be used as the delimiter.

Comment: @Mack: Yes but what I'm trying to tell you is that the single null terminators in the string returned from `GetEnvironmentStrings()` does not signify the end of a string. It signifies the end of a substring within the string. You therefore can't use it to determine when there's no more substrings to process. `GetEnvironmentStrings()` use a double null terminator to signify the ultimate end of the entire string. That's why your while loop doesn't work. The format of the string returned from the function [is described here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/10/08/9904646.aspx).

Comment: Ugh, why I am I responding I dont know. The whole point is to separate the long string into environ vars & each environvar in the string ends in a '\0' char. I aint searching for the end of a string!

Comment: @Mack: I know you're not searching for the end of the string. But your `while` loop needs to somehow know at some point when there's no more environvar strings to process, otherwise it will run forever. That's why you need to look for the double null terminator, not a single null terminator. There's even [a blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/10/08/9904646.aspx) that tells you how to do that correctly.

Comment: @Mack: `GetEnvironmentStrings()` (the name should have been a hint) doesn't give you one string.  It gives you a whole bunch of strings, packed adjacently in memory, terminated by an empty string.  There's no such thing as an embedded '\0' character in a C-style string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have expected this to exit immediately, but actually the man page says:

> The terminating null character is considered to be part of the string; therefore if `c` is `'\0'`, the functions locate the terminating `'\0'`.

Of course, the result of `pos = strchr(environVar, '\0');` is that `*pos == '\0'` and `strlen(pos) == 0`.  So you always copy exactly zero characters.  Not useful.

You also set `environVar = pos;`, without skipping over the NUL character.  So the next call to `strchr` returns `environVar` and no more progress is ever made.

---

**You've also forgotten to initialize `buffer`, you're passing a wild pointer to `strncpy` which will corrupt a random part of memory.** This bug will probably rear its ugly head as soon as you fix the fact that the length parameter is always zero.

Comment: Do you know how I can copy the character from index 0 to pos using a cstring function?

Comment: @Mack: Yeah -- `strcpy`.  You don't even need to tell it the length, it will find the first `\0` and stop there.

Comment: ah I got it, it does point to the NULL terminator each time, so no prgress is made. So I changed one little bit: I do environVar = ++pos; & it works. Thanks :)

Comment: @Mack: Except for the little problem that `pos` will never be NULL. (Note NULL is a pointer, NUL is the `'\0'` character.  They're spelled differently).  So your while loop still never ends, although now you do walk over all the strings instead of getting stuck.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this a bit more simply and without relying on the C Standard Library functions:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    const char* environment = "x=x\0y=y\0z=z\0";

    std::vector<std::string> environment_strings;
    const char* current_string = environment;

    while (*current_string)
    {
        environment_strings.push_back(current_string);
        current_string += environment_strings.back().length() + 1;
    }
}
```

The `std::string` constructor used here takes characters from the pointed-to array until it reaches a `\0`.  We then move to the next string, which begins one character past the end of the previous string.  It stops when it reaches an "empty" string (the double null terminator that ends the sequence).

Comment: This invloves iterating over every char which is a little inefficient. I'd rather use cstring functions. Plus the win32 function GetEnvironmentStrings() returns a char* not a const char* which makes things more difficult with cstrings

Comment: @Mack:  I don't understand your comment.  Of course it involves iterating over every character; how else do you think you can determine the lengths of the component strings?  What do you think `strchr` does?  How inefficient do you really think this is?  (Are you going to have million-character long environment strings?)  There is no reason to use the `<cstring>` functions if you're already using `std::string` and friends.  Why do you think it is a problem that the pointer returned by the `GetEnvironmentStrings()` function is not const-qualified?

Comment: @Mack: Don't you think `strchr` involves iterating over every char?  (Actually, it might not, if your CPU has SIMD, but the `std::string` constructor should be just as smart).  And you (try to) copy the data twice, once to `buffer`, then again in the `std::string` constructor.  James's version only copies it once, directly into the string.  (And both versions may make an additional copy during `push_back`, if C++0x is available then `emplace_back` would be slightly better)

Comment: And I can't even delete my answer to force him to accept your better one... :-p

Comment: You could make it work with double null terminated strings - sio you can reliably include nulls. I don't know enough about the standards to know whether an extra null is added to the initial sting. But useful for a string "created" dynamically.

Comment: @Boofhead: I don't understand your comment; to what is your comment in reply?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    vector<string> res;

    const char *s = "=::=::\0system=blah\0othervar=blah\0";
    const char *p = s;

    while (*s != '\0')
    {
        p = strchr (p, '\0');
        res.push_back (s);
        s = ++p;
    }
}
```

Comment: The condition in the for loop is useless, `strchr(p, '\0')` can never return NULL.

Comment: @Ben: It returns exactly NULL if character is not found. But in this particular case - you are right.

Comment: OK, here is a result after one more glass of wine, LOL

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong.

```
strncpy( buffer, environVar, strlen(pos) );
```

pos is positioned at the first null, and has a length of zero.  You probably want strlen(environVar).

This line is probably causing the infinite loop:

```
environVar = pos;
```

Since pos is positioned at \0, it is going to return that same pointer.  Try pos + 1.